# Count number of returned rows from join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, numbers

i want to count the numbers of each returned row from a join for each different id, but i habe no idea how to do that, for example

```
SELECT a.ticket_id, a.class, a.create, b.info, b.info_count
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
ON a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id
```

```
ticket_id info_count
--------- ----------
    1         1
    1         2
    2         1
    2         2
    2         3
    3         1
    3         2
    3         3
    3         4
```

Is there a way do to that? Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: I understand that you are showing your expected output, but not your sample data. Would you please show sample data for both tables as well?

Comment: You select 5 columns, but the expected result has only 2 columns. Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `count()` and `group by`

```
SELECT a.ticket_id,count(b.info_count)
FROM a LEFT JOIN b
ON a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id
group by a.ticket_id
```

OR you can use `row_number()` if u want a count for each id

```
SELECT a.ticket_id, a.class, a.create, b.info, b.info_count,
row_number() over(partition by a.ticket_id order by a.create) as cnt
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
ON a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "returned row".  If you mean the number of rows, you would use:

```
SELECT a.ticket_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b
     ON a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id
GROUP BY a.ticket_id;
```

The sum of `cnt` values will be the total rows in the result set.

If you mean "matching rows in `b`", then it would be Fahmi's answer:

```
SELECT a.ticket_id, COUNT(b.ticket_id) as cnt
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b
     ON a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id
GROUP BY a.ticket_id;
```

The sum of `cnt` will not include unmatched rows in `b`.

If this is what you want, then this might be faster (it is worth testing):

```
select a.ticket_id,
       (select count(*) from b where a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id) as cnt
from a;
```

In particular, this can make effective use of an index on `b(ticket_id)` -- an index which is useful for all the queries.